# setAsync and getAsync issues with returned HTML in Outlook 365 API

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are having an issue with window.Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync modifying html that we send to it. Specifically the signature.

Original html passed in here:

```
window.Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(html, { coercionType: window.Office.CoercionType.Html }, (response) => {
    if (response.error) {
        console.error('setBody Error :', response.error);
        callback && callback(response.error);
    } else {
        callback && callback(null);
    }
});
```

contains an image in a signature with the src looking something like this:
`<img class="EmojiInsert" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2w...`

However after we pass it into setAsync and call `window.Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('html', ...)`
immediately, what we receive back is:
`<img class="EmojiInsert" src=""`
in the signature.

This only applies to signature images, any other image attached to the email is returned correctly.

Is there something that we are not doing right?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security, we do not support attaching images directly through the SetAsync apis. In order to insert an image inline, you need to first add it as an attachment with the `isInline` property set to `true`, then insert your image tag with `src='cid:myImage.jpg'`. Check out the tutorial [here](https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Foffice%2Fdev%2Fadd-ins%2Freference%2Fobjectmodel%2Frequirement-set-1.5%2Foffice.context.mailbox.item%23addfileattachmentasyncuri-attachmentname-options-callback&data=04%7C01%7Cannich%40microsoft.com%7Ce7b3c241ba264c0eee5408d62fbb333a%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636748878396695405%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwifQ%3D%3D%7C-1&sdata=4zcKjXG6%2B27AgNV2L9mispDsAI7waVODtgs0G02jkIo%3D&reserved=0) for a quick example.

Comment: I just want to confirm - we need to host all images from user signatures? There is no alternative at the current time?

Comment: Currently you must do that. (the only source for adding attachments right now is a hosted file). We are aware of demands to add attachments via Base64, but I cannot confirm if or when that feature will be coming.